# How to install mongo-scala-driver for scala version 3 using sbt?

Tags: mongodb, scala, sbt

I am trying to install mongo-scala-driver but I am running into this error:

[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.mongodb.scala:mongo-scala-driver_3:4.2.3

My build.sbt file looks like this:

```
name := "project"
version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "3.0.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.2.9"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.9" % "test"

libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "4.2.3"
```

I am wondering if it is failing because I am using scala version 3.0.2 whereas the last Scala version that the Mongo Scala docs have listed is 2.12. The instructions I am following are here:
https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/driver-scala/getting-started/installation/.

I am new to Scala so this could very well be a different problem, but I am having trouble finding any solutions.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Scala artifacts lack binary compatibility (cross major versions) which means that a library `x` compiled with `Scala 2.12.x` can not be used with `Scala 2.13.x`. So, library owners compile their libraries for multiple Scala versions and publish multiple binary packages.

So, for any library `abc` developed by organization `org.xyx`, they will publish artifacts named `abc_2.11`, `abc_2.12`, `abc_2.13`.

So, if you are working with `Scala 2.12` and want to use version `1.2.3` of this library, then you can include this library as follows,

```scala
libraryDependencies += "org.xyz" % "abc_2.12" % "1.2.3"
```

Note that we did not use `%%` to add the above dependency.

This `%%` is a special helper provided by `sbt` which automatically appends the major scala version to artifact name.

So, the above example can be re-written as

```scala
scalaVersion := "2.12.14"

libraryDependencies += "org.xyz" %% "abc" % "1.2.3"
```

`sbt` will automatically convert `abc` to `abc_2.12`.

So, for using any library, you need to first check whether it's available for your Scala version or not.

Lets look at `cats-core`. We can check maven central for available versions,

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.typelevel/cats-core

[image]

We can see that `cats-core` `version 2.6.1` is available for `Scala` `2.12`, `2.13` and `3`. We will be able to use it with `Scala 3`.

Now, look at `mongo-scala-driver`. We can check maven central for available versions,

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb.scala/mongo-scala-driver

[image: Maven Central - mongo-scala-driver]

As you can see that the latest version `4.2.3` is only publised for `Scala` `2.11`, `2.12` and `2.13`. Not yet available for `Scala 3`. So, you can not use it with `Scala 3`.

`Scala 3` has major differences from `Scala 2.12` and `Scala 2.13`. `mongo-scala-driver` heavily uses `macros` which were dropped in `Scala 3`, so it will require a major rewrite to supports `Scala 3` and thus it is unlikely to get Scala 3 copatibiltiy in near future.

If any of your dependeices is missing in Scala 3, then you should just stay with `Scala 2.12` or `Scala 2.13`.

For this particular case, you can use `mongo-java-driver` with any version of Scala (as it does not depend on Scala at all).

```
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.scala" % "mongo-java-driver" % "4.2.3"
```

Comment: Note that it's possible to use Scala 2.13 libraries with Scala 3 though (thanks to a special compatibility between 2.13 and 3.0) but only if the library does not use macros.

Comment: Yes, but there are more conditions (compiler plugins and scala reflect being the big one's). Also, as most libraries depend on some other libraries (which depend on other libraries) so in many cases these "checks" just end up like a rabbit hole.

Comment: True, it's just that your answer is very complete and could be enriched with this piece of info ;)